# How to pass an argument returned by a python function to a program and analyse it with GDB?

Tags: python, gdb

Let's say i have this function:

```
python -c "print '\x98\x84\x04\x08'"
```

And when runnning a binary i can pass an argument to it (through the function fgets for instance).

How do you start GDB on this binary AND with the result of the python command ?

p.s: all of this in the same command line obviously :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is like this:

```
gdb --args name-of-your-binary $(python -c "print '\x98\x84\x04\x08'")
```

This will put result of python print into argv[1].